# R computing mean, median, variance from file with frequency distribution

Tags: r, statistics

I am very new to R tool and my questions might be a little too obvious.

I have a file that has the following data:

```
Score     Frequency

 100         10

 200         30

 300         40
```

How do I read this file and compute the mean, median, variance and standard deviation?

If this above table was just raw scores without any frequency information, then I can do this:

x <- scan(file="scores.txt", what = integer())

median(x)

and so on, but I am not able to understand how to do these computations when given a frequency table.

Answer (score 8):

Read the data with `read.table` (read `?read.table` for reading from a file).  Then, expand the data by creating a vector of individual scores. We can then write a function to get the desired statistics.  You can, of course, calculate each individually if you don't wish to write a function.

```
d <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Score     Frequency
 100         10
 200         30
 300         40")

d2 <- rep(d$Score, d$Frequency)  ## expands the data by frequency of score

multi.fun <- function(x) {
    c(mean = mean(x), median = median(x), var = var(x), sd = sd(x))
}

multi.fun(d2)
#      mean     median        var         sd 
# 237.50000  250.00000 4905.06329   70.03616
```

Comment: What is the solution if frequencies are huge, e.g. you cannot expand the data in the memory?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what format you input file is in you can use `read.csv("scores.txt")`.  You can change the separator with `read.csv("scores.txt", sep="\t")`.  If you data doesn't have a header, you can use the option `header=F`.

I am going to use a `,` since it is easier to read here.

INPUT FILE

```
Score,Frequency
100,10
200,30
300,40
```

R Source Code

```
x <- read.csv("scores.txt")
mean(x$Score)
median(x$Score)
var(x$Score)
mean(x$Score)
sd(x$Score)
```

R Output

```
> mean(x$Score)
[1] 200
> median(x$Score)
[1] 200
> var(x$Score)
[1] 10000
> mean(x$Score)
[1] 200
> sd(x$Score)
[1] 100
```

If you want to include the frequency.

R Source Code

```
x <- read.csv("scores.txt")
mean(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
median(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
var(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
mean(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
sd(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
```

R Output

```
> mean(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
[1] 237.5
> x <- read.csv("scores.txt")
> mean(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
[1] 237.5
> median(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
[1] 250
> var(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
[1] 4905.063
> mean(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
[1] 237.5
> sd(rep(x$Score, x$Frequency))
[1] 70.03616
```

Comment: The rep function was what I was looking for from past hour! thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it the way you would have done it manually:

Let s be the vector of scores and f the vector of frequencies.

```
Sx = sum(s*f)
Sx2 = sum((s^2)*f)
n = sum(f)
theMean = Sx/n
SSx = Sx2 - n*theMean^2
sVar = SSx/(n-1)
ssd = sqrt(sVar)
```

This avoids the use of rep, which is a hassle when numbers are large.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines <- readLines("scores.txt")[-1]
mat <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(
    strsplit(gsub(".*(\\d+).*(\\d+).*", "\\1,\\2", lines), ","))),
  ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
print(summary(mat[, 1]))
print(summary(mat[, 2]))
```