# Calculating grouped variance from a frequency table in R

Tags: r, frequency, variance, frequency-distribution

How can I, in R calculate the overall variance and the variance for each group from a dataset that looks like this (for example):

```
Group Count Value
A      3     5
A      2     8
B      1     11
B      3     15
```

I know to calculate the variance as a whole, ignoring the groups I would do:
`var(rep(x$Value, x$Count)),`
but how do I automatically calculate the variance for each group accounting for the frequency? E.g., the variance for group A, group B, etc.,.. I would like my output to have the following headers:

```
Group, Total Count, Group Variance
```

I have also reviewed this link; [R computing mean, median, variance from file with frequency distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644481/r-computing-mean-median-variance-from-file-with-frequency-distribution) which is  different (does not have the group component) so this is not a duplicate.

thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is using `data.table`.  Convert the data.frame to data.table (`setDT`) and get the `var` of "Value" and `sum` of "Count" by "Group".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(GroupVariance=var(rep(Value, Count)),
                      TotalCount=sum(Count)) , by = Group]
#    Group GroupVariance TotalCount
#1:     A           2.7          5
#2:     B           4.0          4
```

a similar way using `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df1, Group) %>% 
      summarise(GroupVariance=var(rep(Value,Count)), TotalCount=sum(Count))
#     Group GroupVariance TotalCount
#1     A           2.7          5
#2     B           4.0          4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick wrapper with base R. First step is to grow your data set by Count, and then calculate variance by group

```
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Count), ]
with(df1, tapply(Value, Group, var))
#   A   B 
# 2.7 4.0
```

Or similarly

```
aggregate(Value ~ Group, df1, function(x) c(Var = var(x), Count = length(x)))
#   Group Value.Var Value.Count
# 1     A       2.7         5.0
# 2     B       4.0         4.0
```

Comment: I am trying to figure it out - but the aggregate option isn't working for me. Not an error, just the wrong values... your first option and the "data table" one, works.

Comment: Are you using `df` or `df1` in the `aggregate`. It's important to use `df1`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. works now. So the aggregate is an alternative to the "with" option here. Thanks for the help. So many different ways to do the same thing- trying to figure out which one is the mount intuitive.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, is it possible to compute variance with base R without rep() function? I have probabilities but don't have a frequency table?

Comment: @Nick The `rep` function has nothing to do with `var`. It was used to extend the data size.